# Javascript Issue with creating a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a link like this:

```
$("#div_"+id+" .boxcontent").html("<div align='right'><a href='javascript:loadHistory('" + item.f + "','" + boxtitle + "');'>Load History</a></div>");
```

but it is breaking the code,

I am trying to make it like this:

```html
<div align='right'><a href='javascript:loadHistory("sender","receiver");'>Load History</a></div>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You are closing quotes incorrectly. Change from - <a href='javascript:loadHistory('" + item.f + "','" + boxtitle + "');'> to <a href='javascript:loadHistory(\"" + item.f + "\",\"" + boxtitle + "\");>

Comment: That worked, Cool. I do not know how to accept your answer

Comment: @CuriousMind please don't post code blocks in comments, if you must, format it using backticks ``

Comment: voyeger I have posted it as answer, please accept it. @TJ Sorry, my mistake, I just typed in a hurry and posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using quotes incorrectly.
Change from:

```html
<a href='javascript:loadHistory('" + item.f + "','" + boxtitle + "');'>
```

to:

```html
<a href='javascript:loadHistory(\"" + item.f + "\",\"" + boxtitle + "\");>
```

Note I have escaped the double quotes `"` using `\`.